# Links not working in an absolute container with a positive z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem can be seen on the website I am developing https://manu354.github.io/portfolio/

The links in the header cannot be clicked. After a quick search on SO I realized this was because my div was positioned absolute. I had positioned it absolute, so it didn't take up any space in my page layout. To fix this, multiple answers said to add a `z-index : 10;` to my div. This let me click the links (Pointer / hover functionality worked) and completely fixed the problems for my external links to Facebook, or Twitter. However my internal functional links e.g `href="#welcome"`were clickable, however they didn't move to the area they were meant to (works if the div is positioned relatively).

For example (the actual codes much longer, and uses revolution slider)

```
<div style="position:absolute; z-index:1;">

<a href="#welcome" target="_self" style="z-index: 10;>

</div>
```

Anybody know a fix for this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm getting quite alot of downvotes and hate on this question, I even just had one user email through my webpage saying:  
"You can help us by not posting stupid questions on Stackoverflow !" I really don't understand what is wrong with this question and find it perfectly legitimate. Could anyone point me out what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you didn't put the ending double quotes in the a(anchor) tag the below code can help:

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>codedamn HTML Playground</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="position:absolute; z-index:1;">
       <a href="#welcome" target="_self" style="z-index: 10;">Hello world</a>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well it doesnt work because your  links to an id "welcome" but the div's id is "welcome_forcefullwidth".

[Welcome ID](http://image.prntscr.com/image/77a0e538d0e247178da46d57a1f58d19.png)

If you remove "_forcefullwidth" or add on your href "_forcefullwidth" it will work

Not to mention that the rest of the IDs are nowhere to be found

I see on your website a lot of inline style and the website is too complex as it should. The code is not that clean.

Comment: But it works as soon as I remove `position : absolute`

Comment: And now looking at my HTML code, the div I want to go to, IS called Id="welcome"

Comment: can you upload an image so we know where this id is located?

Comment: Well it really shouldn't be a problem with the id, since it works perfectly as soon as I remove the absolute positioning. The div I want to go to is on line `326` starting with `<div id="welcome" class="rev_slider fullscreenbanner" style="display:none;" data-version="5.3.0.2">`

Comment: one question... You are using one-page site which in my opinion is perfect for this kind of website. BUT, why dont you use a fixed navigation so it will be accessible at all times? There is no point to use such navigation when it is not fixed. When someone goes to the bottom, he should have a way to go to the top not only bei scrolling. A click makes users easier..

Comment: I just started working on the project, I understand it's very messy and not the best code. I myself am not very experienced in developing websites. I am going to make the nav fixed, I just haven't got around to doing that yet.